# R - Special characters reading with read_fwf

Tags: r, encoding, readr

I'm trying to convert a large list of strings to dataframe with *read_fwf* function from *readr* package and I'm having some troubles with special characters like accents. Could anyone help me with this please? I’m not used to deal with encodings :(

```
library(readr)
fw <- fwf_widths(c(2,13,2), col_names = c('A','B','C'))
x <- read_fwf('00StackOvérflow00\n',
                      col_positions = fw)
```

The result is:

```
A     B                  C    
00    "StackOv\xe9rflow" 00
```

As you can see the accent is gone...

Thankss!!

Xevi

Comment: I believe you can specify a different encoding method (not UTF-8, or whatever the default is) using the `locale` argument. I can check it out later when I get to my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by changing the encoding via `locale` to `LATIN1`:

```
library(readr)
fw <- fwf_widths(c(2,13,2), col_names = c('A','B','C'))
x <- read_fwf('00StackOvérflow00\n',
                      col_positions = fw, locale = locale(encoding = 'LATIN1'))
```

Returning:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  A     B             C    
  <chr> <chr>         <chr>
1 00    StackOvérflow 00
```